# How to remove several symbols from a string in BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have strings which contain numbers like that:

```
a20cdac0_19221bdc12022bab3fe05a43df4a7dbe
```

I need to get only symbols after underscore symbol:

```
19221bdc12022bab3fe05a43df4a7dbe
```

Unfortunately, the amount of those symbols is always different, so I can't use just RIGHT function.

I know that probably REGEXP might help, but I can't understand how to use that exactly. Will be very grateful for the help.

Comment: will the format always x_y where the underscore is always the divider?

Comment: yes, so far I saw only one underscore divider in such a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (using regexp)

```
regexp_extract(value, r'_(.*)') regexp_approach
```

if to apply to sample value from your question

```
regexp_extract('a20cdac0_19221bdc12022bab3fe05a43df4a7dbe', r'_(.*)') regexp_approach
```

result is

[image]

Yet, another regexp option is to use `regexp_replace` as in below example

```
regexp_replace(value, r'^.*?_', '')
```

Note: using `split` in this case is also an option unless you have more than one `_` in which case you will get part between first and second `_`

```
split(value, '_')[safe_offset(1)]
```

Also, as you can see you need to use `safe` to prevent error in cases when `_` is absent

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function like this

```
select split('a20cdac0_19221bdc12022bab3fe05a43df4a7dbe','_')[ORDINAL(2)];
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split